# PowerShell ForEach Loop to Add UserPrincipalName and object ID to a file

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, azure-active-directory

I have a file of user emails. I need to gather their UPNs and object IDs.

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$user.EmailAddress'"
```

- I'm using this line to query AzureAD and it works perfectly. However when I place it in a loop I can't seem to get any data.

```
import-csv .\Book4.csv | ForEach-Object{
    Get-AzureADUser -Filter "PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$_.EmailAddress'" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectID
} | Export-Csv -Path .\Book4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong. I thought this would be something simple but I've been stuck for an hour. The CSV file has three column headers: EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName, ObjectID

Comment: Alternatively, since you already have the UPN of the users you could use `-SearchString $_.UPN` (where `UPN` would be the CSV header).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$_.EmailAddress'"` doesn't work as intended, because the attempted *property access* on variable `$_`, `.EmailAddress`, isn't effective:

**Inside `"..."`, an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), you need `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) in order to access a variable's *properties***<sup>[1]</sup>, call methods on it, or, more generally embed entire *statements*.

Therefore, use the following string instead:

```
"PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$($_.EmailAddress)'"
```

Also, you're mistakenly trying to read from and write back to the same file (`.\Book4.csv`) in the same pipeline, which doesn't work (without additional effort), as discussed in [Allen Wu's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68109012/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Without enclosing in `$(...)`, `"...$_.EmailAddress..."` cause `$_` to be expanded *by itself*, whereas `.EmailAddress` is used *verbatim*. Compare `Write-Output "$HOME.Length"` to `Write-Output "$($HOME.Length)"`, for instance.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

@mklement0 is correct.

But another important thing is that we can't read from and write back to the same file in the same pipeline. Unless you make sure that the input file is read into memory, in full, before its lines are sent through the pipeline.

Use this:

```
$users = import-csv E:\temp\Book4.csv | ForEach-Object{
    Get-AzureADUser -Filter "PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$($_.EmailAddress)'" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectID
} 

$users | Export-Csv -Path E:\temp\Book4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Good point about trying to write back to the same file in the same pipeline. Note that there's a simple workaround, however, which allows sticking with a single pipeline: Enclose the file-reading command (`Import-Csv`) in `(...)`, which forces reading in full, up front: `(import-csv E:\temp\Book4.csv) | ForEach-Object { Get-AzureADUser -Filter "PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$($_.EmailAddress)'" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectID } | Export-Csv -Path E:\temp\Book4.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: I appreciate your help!